# Why the union of two classes is a class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Under NBG, suppose we have two classes $A$ and $B$, we wish to form the class of their union by defining {$x$|(x is a set) $\wedge$ (p($x$))} where p(x)="$x \in A$ $\lor$ $x \in B$ ", but according to the axiom of class formation, in property $p$ the class variable should not appear, isn't that saying the p(x) defined before is not valid? Thank you

Comment: What is your source ? See [Class existence axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Class_existence_axioms_and_axiom_of_regularity): we have axioms for intersection and complement. The union is the complement of the intersection of complements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was looking at topology by james dugundji, in the axiom of class formation, it says "for each property p in which only set variables are quantified and in which the class variable does not appear", which confuses me as here $A$ and $B$ are both classes, are they counted for class variables as well?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah i see, so it's saying in $p$ of $A$, $p$ should not contain the class $A$ which is characterised by $p$?

Comment: Exactly.........

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA now it makes sense, thank you

Comment: The reason is very simple: we are defining a new "object" $A$ and we use as defining condition a "statement" $p(x)$; obviously, the statement cannot itself refer to $A$, because $A$ is not defined ... prior to the definition.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You should add that as an answer ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I think your last comment needs some qualification: in many situations there are valid principles of recursive definition that do allow the defining property of an object to refer to that object. Tarski's axiom in Tarski-Grothendieck set theory is essentially a definitional principle of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

See [Class existence axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Class_existence_axioms_and_axiom_of_regularity): we have axioms for intersection and complement. The union is the complement of the intersection of complements.

The definition is correct; see page 18:

> "the variable $C$ does not appear [in property $p(x)$]".

The restriction is only on the new class variable we are defining through $p(x)$.

Formally, we have: $(x ∈ C) ↔ [\text{set}(x) ∧ (x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ B)]$.